# How to store email with attachment in database

Tags: c#, save, email-attachments, eml

In my program, I receive a `.eml` files via drag-and-drop onto my form.

I am able to store this file without any problem. Also, when re-opening the (copy) of the dropped `.eml` file, I am able to open it in the default application (i.e. default mail client).

I can see the attached files, but, when trying to open them, nothing happens.

Is there a way to *encapsulate* the attachments of a mail into the `.eml` file?

I know I could simply store the attachment files somewhere, but then, I'd have to amend the `.eml` to take into account the new location, which is a hassle that, in my case, I'd really want to avoid...

EDIT:
- Storing the `.eml` file is done by converting the file to a `byte[]` array, which is then stored to the database.

```
byte[] savedToDB = File.ReadAllBytes(docPath);
```

Previewing the file is done via following (pseudo-) code:

1) Load the `byte[]` array from database

2) Save as a temporary file with following code:

```
string tmpPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", ".eml");  
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(tmpPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {  
      fs.Write(bytesFromDB, 0, bytesFromDB.Length);  
      fs.Close();  
}  
File.SetAttributes(@tmpPath, File.GetAttributes(tmpPath) | FileAttributes.Temporary);  
if (File.Exists(tmpPath)) {  
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);  
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
It appears the problem lies in the way I display the file, not the way I store it.

Actually, my code is as follows:

```
// see code above for storing the temporary file...
// replace the following line 
// System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);  
// by following code...
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
    worker.DoWork += (s, e) => {
      System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
      // wait 1 second at least!
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
      p.WaitForExit();
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => {
      File.Delete(path);
    };
```

The problem is that the `BackgroundWorker` terminates while the preview window is still open - which deletes the temporary file and hence, path to the attachments are lost.

So the question I have: is there a proper way to ensure the file is deleted once it is closed? If not, will the temporary file (in the temp folder) be flushed automatically by the system and, if so, when?

I need to make sure the opened files are not piling up onto the client's disk...

Comment: The .eml should contain the attachments. Can you open the attachments on the original file?

Comment: I confirm, attachment opens on original mail but NOT on stored email. I update my comment, as maybe, it is because of the way I store and restore the documents...

Comment: So, you can open the attachments from the original .eml file but when you save it somewhere else and then get it back (as .eml) and try to open it, you cannot see the attachments?

Comment: Please provide more details (such as relevant code) on how you save the file.

Comment: Yacoub, I added sample code in the original post.Please note that I am able to open attachments when opening the dropped `.eml` file using the temporary path of the dropped `.eml`file, but I am not able to preview it when loading from database...

Comment: If you compare the original file and the store file byte by byte, are they the same? Can you show the code how you read and store the original EML file?

Comment: Hi Yacoub, I found the problem, but I'm not sure I'm able to fix it - it's related to the fact I try to clean-up the file after previewing it... see update above

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem happens only if outlook is already open? Test your code while outlook is closed.

Comment: You are absolutely correct - it works if my mail client (actually Thunderbird, but that's irrelevant) is closed and launched by the process, but not if the mail client is already opened outside the app.

Comment: This happens because if the mail client is already open, then the process that you create newly will detect that and pass the email filename to the existing process to open, and then the new process will terminate immediately.

Comment: You are right. Any suggestion as per temporary file deletion in that case?

Comment: Can you assume anything about the mail client that the users are going to use? If so, you might want to look for special command line switches for the mail client that will force a new instance of the mail client to open.